# custom list view with custom dialog set adapter in android.

Tags: android

In My `listview` when i click on change `button` open a custom dialog box .
Enter name of item.

*I am writing update list view code on OK button in custom dialog* .

gives me following error :

```
01-21 12:33:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(1789): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

[image]

Comment: can you share some code.. how u r doing this